# Dijkstra's algorithm with adjacency matrix

Tags: julia

I'm trying to implement the following code from [here](https://github.com/dileep-kishore/CombOpt.jl/blob/master/src/dijkstra.jl) but it won't work correctly.

What I want is the shortest path distances from a source to all nodes and also the predecessors. Also, I want the input of the graph to be an adjacency matrix which contains all of the edge weights.

I'm trying to make it work in just one function so I have to rewrite it. If I'm right the original code calls other functions (from graph.jl for example).

I don't quite understand how to rewrite the for loop which calls the adj() function.

Also, I'm not sure if the input is correct in the way the code is for now.

```
function dijkstra(graph, source)
    node_size = size(graph, 1)
    dist = ones(Float64, node_size) * Inf
    dist[source] = 0.0
    Q = Set{Int64}()  # visited nodes
    T = Set{Int64}(1:node_size)  # unvisited nodes
    pred = ones(Int64, node_size) * -1
    while condition(T)
        # node selection
        untraversed_nodes = [(d, k) for (k, d) in enumerate(dist) if k in T]
        if minimum(untraversed_nodes)[1] == Inf
            break # Break if remaining nodes are disconnected
        end
        node_ind = untraversed_nodes[argmin(untraversed_nodes)][2]
        push!(Q, node_ind)
        delete!(T, node_ind)
        # distance update
        curr_node = graph.nodes[node_ind]
        for (neigh, edge) in adj(graph, curr_node)
            t_ind = neigh.index
            weight = edge.cost
            if dist[t_ind] > dist[node_ind] + weight
                dist[t_ind] = dist[node_ind] + weight
                pred[t_ind] = node_ind
            end
        end
    end
    return dist, pred
end
```

So if I'm trying it with the following matrix

```
A = [0 2 1 4 5 1; 1 0 4 2 3 4; 2 1 0 1 2 4; 3 5 2 0 3 3; 2 4 3 4 0 1; 3 4 7 3 1 0]
```

and source 2 i would like to get the distances in a vector dist and the predeccessors in anothe vectore pred.

Right now I'm getting

ERROR: type Array has no field nodes

> Stacktrace:  [1] getproperty(::Any, ::Symbol) at .\sysimg.jl:18

I guess I have to rewrite it a bit more.

I m  thankful for any help.

Comment: The original source you reference has `graph::Graph`.  It's not an `Array`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `graph[i,j]` is a length of path from `i` to `j` (your graph is directed looking at your data), and it is a `Matrix` with non-negative entries, where `0` indicates no edge from `i` to `j`, a minimal rewrite of your code should be something like:

```
function dijkstra(graph, source)
    @assert size(graph, 1) == size(graph, 2)
    node_size = size(graph, 1)
    dist = fill(Inf, node_size)
    dist[source] = 0.0
    T = Set{Int}(1:node_size)  # unvisited nodes
    pred = fill(-1, node_size)
    while !isempty(T)
        min_val, min_idx = minimum((dist[v], v) for v in T)
        if isinf(min_val)
            break # Break if remaining nodes are disconnected
        end
        delete!(T, min_idx)
        # distance update
        for nei in 1:node_size
            if graph[min_idx, nei] > 0 && nei in T
                possible_dist = dist[min_idx] + graph[min_idx, nei]
                if possible_dist < dist[nei]
                    dist[nei] = possible_dist
                    pred[nei] = min_idx
                end
            end
        end
    end
    return dist, pred
end
```

(I have not tested it extensively, so please report if you find any bugs)

Comment: Thank you very much. After testing it a few times it looks like it works in the way it should be and without any bugs.

Comment: You could also have a look at the implementation here https://github.com/JuliaGraphs/LightGraphs.jl/blob/3f71acda3996c429f5df268649f05b79e85def62/src/shortestpaths/dijkstra.jl